# Call function from another Controller in another file AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

[Call function from another Controller Angular Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562905/call-function-from-another-controller-angular-js)

[Call function from another controller Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602407/call-function-from-another-controller-angularjs)

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/dependency-injection.html

I've been googling around and trying to adapt but I can't figure out.
I have two files: `home.js` and `auth.js`. I created the file `auth.js` because I will need to call the functions inside of it in lot of files.

I can't create simple functions like:

```
function isAuthed(){
  return true;
}
```

Because I'll need to use some AngularJS modules, such as HTTP, therefore I believe I need to create a decent angular js file.
For what I've read so far, in order to call a function from another controller the best and correct way is to use **Services**.

**home.js**

```
var app = angular.module('home', [
    'ngRoute'
]);

app.controller('home', ['$scope', 'authSERVICE', function($scope, authSERVICE){
    console.log(authSERVICE.hasCredentials());
}]);
```

**auth.js**

```
var app = angular.module('auth', []);

app.service('authSERVICE', ['$http', function($http){

    this.hasCredentials = function(){

        if(window.localStorage.getItem('email') != null && window.localStorage.getItem('password') != null){
            return true;
        }   
    }

    this.login = function(email, password){

        // Base64 function is from a simple JS file.
        var auth = Base64.encode('username:password');

        $http.get('http://localhost/project/api/webservice/getCategories', {

            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth },
            params : {
                email: email,
                password: password,
            }

        }).success(function(response){

            return true;

        }).error(function(response){

            return false;

        }); 
    }
}]);
```

This does not work and I receive an error on console poiting to: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=authSERVICEProvider%20%3C-%20authSERVICE
I kind of understand what's the error information telling me. Although, I still need and want to have two different files.

**EDIT**: Btw, in the `index.html` file I've called the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="application/controllers/home.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="application/controllers/auth.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Ved answer I manage to figure it out. **Solved**.

```
var app = angular.module('home', [
    'ngRoute',
    'auth'
]);
```